# How to use a Priority Queue?

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue

Will a priority queue work if I want to process elements in FIFO, but have priority to an element that is greater than a certain number? What do I use if I want FIFO but also want some element to have priority if it is greater than 60?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you use a priority queue.  If the element's priority is less than your threshold amount (such as 60), then simply assign it a constant priority (such as 1).  Those lower elements will go in the queue FIFO.

Comment: "Those lower elements will go in the queue FIFO." Assuming you're talking about a heap-based priority queue, that's only partly true. Items with equal priority will be inserted in order, but the first time you remove an item, or the first time you insert an item that has a higher priority, the order of items will change. They definitely will not come out of the queue in the same order you inserted them.

Comment: Ah -- good point.  I hadn't thought about the current best implementation being heap-based.  Quite right.